# Setup Spark for CI, how to mock Hive tables

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive

In a Java app, with Spark 1.6.2, I want to test on a CI env (travis or gitlabCI) some Spark SQL queries that use tables (from Apache Hive in production).

How can I register some tables that a Spark application could use without an external Hive metastore?

Note: I cant do it inside the Java program.

Answer (score 4):

You can run your unit tests using the embedded Hive that comes out of the box with spark-hive:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Using your unit test framework of choice you create a local SparkContext and HiveContext:

```
// TODO: set this up before running all your tests
val conf = new SparkConf().
  setMaster("local[*]").
  setAppName("test").
  set("spark.ui.enabled", "false").
  set("spark.app.id", "SparkHiveTests").
  set("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
// default directory is /user/hive/warehouse which doesn't exist on my local machine so use a different dir
hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", "/tmp/hive/warehouse")
```

Then you can create/drop tables and run queries using the embedded Hive!

```
// data will persist in this directory so drop the table to get a clean run if it exists
hiveContext.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS src")
hiveContext.sql("CREATE TABLE src (key INT, value STRING)")
hiveContext.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'src/test/resources/kv1.txt' INTO TABLE src")
val result = hiveContext.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM src").collect().head
assert(result(0) === 3l)
```

Sorry for the Scala here but it should be very similar in Java. If it doesn't make sense let me know and I can try to rewrite it in Java.

Comment: Right, this is what I am doing now, inside the Java app, but I am looking to move this from the app. Maybe something like a shared Spark context.

Comment: @ThomasDecaux What do you mean when you say you want to move this from the app? Do you use junit? This code you would add in some junit tests so that when you setup your CI pipeline all of the tests run.

Comment: I use junit only for unit tests, for func. tests, I am using an external Python script (with Behave), that run severals tasks (hence several Spark contexts).